# How do you add real time viewer count for a livestream?

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

Currently it seems that JWPlayer does not support the display of unique viewers on a livestream (the feature is only available for VOD, according to JWPlayer documentation).

I found the following two links on Wowza's forums:

- [How to send connection and stream statistics to Google Analytics (Analytics)](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-send-connection-and-stream-statistics-to-google-analytics-analytics#usage)
- [How to get connection counts for server, applications, application instances and streams with an HTTP Provider](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-get-connection-counts-for-server-applications-application-instances-and-streams-with-an-http-provider)

Having read through several Stack overflow articles, it appears that unique viewers is defined by more than connection count. Any advice or direction toward (even toward other resources) would be greatly appreciated.

Context: I'm working on a livestreaming and VOD application using JWPlayer, Wowza Streaming Engine, and Wirecast.

Comment: You need to get a list of connections from your server somehow. I don't think this functionality is built-in so you may need to write some Java.

Comment: @tadman Thanks so much for your reply! My friend mentioned looking into fingerprint EFF. Is that what you mean or would it be closer to one of the two links I posted above? (Apologies for my lack of knowledge)

Comment: The Wowza engine has a very comprehensive API that's documented, but not documented in a well-organized way. You'll have to do some digging. It is possible to enumerate connections to a stream and communicate that in a useful form (e.g. JSON over HTTP) to any that request it if you write a module that hooks in to the server.

Comment: @tadman Got it! Thank you so much for your helpful response!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wowza, you can use WMSPanel [unique viewers metric](https://wmspanel.com/reporting/unique). It's based on a combination of IP and user agent within 24 hours time slot.

Comment: Dear Aquary!

Thanks so much for your reply! I'm looking to have it display real time, similar to Twitch.tv where you can see how many unique viewers are on the stream!

Comment: WMSPanel shows realtime connections count. In case of realtime it's similar to unique viewers mostly.